# Why does Makefile re-compile when source file copied from other directory

Tags: makefile

My Makefile has

```
all: depends hello.o

depends:
    cp other_dir/hello.c  ./hello.c

hello.o: hello.c
    cc -c $< -o $@
```

Why it's compiling object file hello.o everytime when i copy source file from other_dir to present working directory

Comment: I answered your question below.  Why are you doing this?  Also, you should mark depends as a `.PHONY: depends` otherwise this will break if you ever create a depends file.  This is makefile question, btw, so you don't need the c, linux and copmiler-errors tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last rule says build `hello.o` from `hello.c` when the latter is newer than the former.  When you copy `hello.c` from depends/ it will update timestamp on hello.c and hence considered newer.

```
$ stat hello.c|grep Modif
Modify: 2022-12-29 23:56:31.041115631 -0500
$ make
cp other_dir/hello.c  ./hello.c
cc    -c -o hello.o hello.c
$ stat hello.c|grep Modif
Modify: 2022-12-29 23:56:42.225075833 -0500
```

You can ask cp, with the option `--preserve=timestamp` to not update timestamp when it's being copied:

```
$ make
cp --preserve=timestamp other_dir/hello.c  ./hello.c
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the correct information